# kendo ui treeview dragend get node id

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview

I have this function to catch the drag end event of a kendo treeview

```
function onDragEnd(e) {
 console.log("Drag end", e.sourceNode, e.dropPosition, e.sourceNode);
}
```

this displays the whole node data such as

```
<li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last" data-uid="[some guid]">
   <div class="k-bot">
      <span class="k-in">[node text]</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

there is also this function to get the text of the node.

```
var text = this.text(e.sourceNode);
```

i was hoping that something like

```
var id = this.id(e.sourceNode);
```

would work but it didn't,

Comment: Found a solution for this:
`var id = ($('[tree_element]').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.sourceNode)).id;`

Answer (score 5):

TreeView

```
$("#treeView").kendoTreeView({
    dragAndDrop: true,
    dataSource: treeViewDataSource,
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dragend: function(e) {
        var tree = $(#treeView).data("kendowTreeview");

        /* tree.dataItem accesses the item's model. You will be able to
         access any field declared in your model*/

        var movingItem = tree.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
        var destinationItem = tree.dataItem(e.destinationNode);

        /*Using firebug, console.log(movingItem) will elaborate better 
        as to what you have access in the object*/

        var movingItemID = movingItem.id;
        var destinationItemID = destinationItem.id;
        //Get the same ID by movingItemID.MyID 
        //(if id:"MyID" set in dataSource's schema)
    }
});
```

Comment: `var tree = $(#treeView).data("kendowTreeview");`
can be also written as
`var tree = e.sender;`